# how to skip a CPT element from the pager by custom field

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, pagination

I'm making a template that shows all the users of a CPT Family like this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php the_post(); ?>
         $marriage        = get_field( 'length_of_marriage' );
         $relationship = get_field('relationship');
         $nickname = get_field('nickname');
    <?php endwhile; ?> 
<?php endif; ?>
<?php echo get_next_post_link( '%link', '<i class="far fa-angle-right"></i>' ); ?>
<?php echo get_previous_post_link( '%link', '<i class="far fa-angle-left"></i>' ); ?>
```

But I need to display only those with "Retained" status when paging and only one item per page should be displayed.

[image]

I tried with the following code but the pager does not work, it shows me any family without respecting the query.

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;    
$args = array (
    'post_type'      => array( 'family' ),
    'paged'          => $paged,   
    'posts_per_page'         => 1,      
);
 $args['meta_query'][] = array(       
    array(
        'key'   => 'status',
        'value' => 'Retained',
        'compare'   => '='
    )
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <?php 
        echo get_field('status');  
        echo '  '.get_field('family_id'); 
    ?>
    <?php $profile_pic = get_field( 'profile_picture' ); ?>
    <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $profile_pic['sizes']['family_large_thumb'] ); ?>" width="300px" height="300px" style="display:block;" />
<?php endwhile;
<?php echo get_next_post_link( '%link', '<i class="far fa-angle-right"></i>' ); ?>
<?php echo get_previous_post_link( '%link', '<i class="far fa-angle-left"></i>' ); ?>
//Clean up after the query and pagination.
wp_reset_query();
```

in the status bar it shows the following link but without respecting the query but when pressing the pager it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you've gone too deep with your `meta_query` argument. The meta query should be an array of arrays; you've got an array of arrays of arrays.

Try:

```
$args['meta_query'] = array(       
    array(
        'key'   => 'status',
        'value' => 'Retained',
        'compare'   => '='
    )
);
```

### References

- [`WP_Meta_Query` class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/) (which is used to parse the `meta_query` argument for `WP_Query`)

Comment: thanks for you answers but that's no problem, my query works fine